# How to setup java warnings per project

Tags: java, maven, netbeans-8

Some java warnings (e.g. for code order) might apply for one project, but not for the other. How can I reflect this fact in NetBeans where the only setting seems to be the `Hint` tab in the editor configuration on application level? I could setup the `checkstyle` maven plugin, but that'd be far from "IDE support" (facing the fact that I'd have to evaluate the output in the browser and then find the referenced line(s) of code in the IDE).

I'm using NetBeans 8.0.2, maven 3.2.5 and and OpenJDK 8.

Answer (score 0):

There's a `Hints` option to configure warnings per project (overwriting the IDE-wide settings in the `Editor` section)